# How to increment class field within a Thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a small garden example.
Garden is a class that has `grow()` function, which checks the amount of water supplied every second. When the amount of water is more than some threshold, garden produces a few flowers.

Here is my first try:

**Garden class**

```
import time

class Garden:
    def __init__(self):
        self.water = 0
        print("Garden built!")

    def grow(self):
        while self.water < 50:
            print("Water supplied: {0}".format(self.water))
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Produced 5 flowers!")
```

**main.py**

```
import time
from garden import Garden
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

def main():
    que = Queue()
    garden = Garden()
    thr = Thread(target=garden.grow).start()
    que_garden = que.get()
    water(que_garden, 20)
    time.sleep(5)
    water(que_garden, 30)
    thr.join()

def water(garden, amount):
    garden.water += amount
    print("Watered with {0}!".format(amount))
```

When I run `main.py` I get the following input:

```
Garden built!
Water supplied: 0
Water supplied: 0
Water supplied: 0
Water supplied: 0
Water supplied: 0
```

So, `grow()` gets constantly called and never gets to `water(que_garden, 20)` line. I expected that once `thr = Thread(target=garden.grow).start()` is called it is not locked until `grow()` finishes but continues to the next line. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
que_garden = que.get()
```

blocks until there is something in the queue. But there is no `que_garden.put()` anywhere.

This works without a queue:

```
import time
from garden import Garden
from threading import Thread

def main():
    garden = Garden()
    thr = Thread(target=garden.grow)
    thr.start()
    water(garden, 20)
    time.sleep(5)
    water(garden, 30)
    time.sleep(5)
    water(garden, 10)
    thr.join()

def water(garden, amount):
    garden.water += amount
    print("Watered with {0}!".format(amount))

main()
```

Output:

```
Garden built!
Water supplied: 0
Watered with 20!
Water supplied: 20
Water supplied: 20
Water supplied: 20
Water supplied: 20
Watered with 30!
Produced 5 flowers!
Watered with 10!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want `garden.grow` instead of `garden.grow()`. The target parameter is a *callable*. You are calling the `grow` method and passing its return value.

Answer (score 0):

From Python Documentation:

> `class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
>   kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)` 
>   This constructor should always be called
>   with keyword arguments. Arguments are:
>
> group should be None; reserved for future extension when a ThreadGroup
>   class is implemented.
>
> **target is the callable object** to be invoked by the run() method.
>   Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

So, Change:

```
thr = Thread(target=garden.grow()).start()
```

to

```
thr = Thread(target=garden.grow).start()
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, typo from my part. But, no, this won't help

Comment: it's python `Queue` build-in

Comment: So, why did you use it in the first place, just curious @minerals?

Comment: Thought it is the way  to access an object in order to modify its field.